# if else multiple conditions comparing rows

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, rows, multiple-conditions

I am strugling with this loop. I want to get "6" in the second row of column "Newcolumn".I get the following error.

```
Error in if (mydata$type_name[i] == "a" && mydata$type_name[i -  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

The code that I created:

```
id  type_name   name    score   newcolumn
1   a   Car 2   2
1   a   van 2   6
1   b   Car 2   2
1   b   Car 2   2

mydata$newcolumn <-c(0)
for (i in 1:length(mydata$id)){
  if ((mydata$type_name [i] == "a") && (mydata$type_name[i-1] == "a") && ((mydata$name[i]) != (mydata$name[i-1]))){
    mydata$newcolumn[i]=mydata$score[i]*3 }
  else {
    mydata$newcolumn[i]=mydata$score[i]*1
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: have you get a solution? I have the same error message when I try to compare elements of row 1 vs elements of row 2. I can't fix the solution yet...

Answer (score 1):

List starts at index 1 in R but like you are doing a i-1 in your loop starting at 1, your list is out of range (i-1=0) so your code can not return a True or False.